# Creating random distance nodes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to have nodes connect to a main node with different distances.

What I have so far:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.empty_graph( 3 , create_using= None)
G.add_edge(0,1)
G.add_edge(0,2)
```

[Graph with equal distance to a main node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvWAh.png)

However, as it can be seen from the image, the distance between the node on either side have equal distance to the main node. Is there a way to have their distance to the main node different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to your question:

**Part 1 - Distance between nodes:**
In network theory, the distance between nodes is represented by the weight of the edge between them. So you can add all your edges with weights to your network with the following line:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from([(0,1,4.0),(0,2,5.0)])
```

You can randomize the weights on the edges above for random distance between nodes.

**Part 2 - Network Visualization:**
I understand that you're more concerned with how the network graph is shown. If you use `nx.draw_random(G)` you can get randomized distances between your nodes, and suggest that you save a picture when you get the desired figure, as it randomizes every time you run.

Hope it helps... :)